# resizing gridview column manually

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that I am displaying email html in.  The columns are very wide because of the way the html is formated.  How can I manually set the size of the column in the gridview?  I tried

Item-Style width =

Header-Style width =

but none of those change the column width, any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you,

```
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message"  HeaderStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="message" />
```

Comment: code would be appreciated. the tag html could be useful if you're speaking about html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this pattern , and you will succeed , good luck ;)

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ISBN" HeaderText="ISBN" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderStyle-Height="40px">
     <HeaderStyle Height="40px"></HeaderStyle>
     <ItemStyle Width="120px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```